# Function that prints dictionary's data line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I've been wanting to print dictionary's data line by line. I came with this basic program

```
numbers = {
    "1": "1: 345435-345-345-34",
    "2": "2: 445345-35-34-345-34",
    "3": "3: 3445-34534534-34345"

}

def print_dict(dictionary):
    for x in dictionary:
        c = dictionary[x]
        for y in c:
            print(y, ": ", dictionary[y])

print_dict(numbers)
```

but it gives me all kinds of errors like:

```
1 :  1: 345435-345-345-34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bot-Programing\satesto.py", line 87, in <module>
    print_dict(numbers)
  File "c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bot-Programing\satesto.py", line 85, in print_dict
    print(y, ": ", dictionary[y])
KeyError: ':'
```

All I am trying to do is to make a function that can take a dictionary as it's argument and then print it's data line by line like this:

```
1: 1: 345435-345-345-34
2: 2: 445345-35-34-345-34
3: 3: 3445-34534534-34345
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `for k, v in numbers.items(): print(k, ':', v)`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the value of each key in the dictionary. Instead, use `f-strings` in Python3.6-Python3.7 or string formatting in Python2-Python3.5:

```
numbers = {
"1": "1: 345435-345-345-34",
"2": "2: 445345-35-34-345-34",
"3": "3: 3445-34534534-34345"

}
print('\n'.join(f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in numbers.items()))
```

String formatting in Python2:

```
print('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in numbers.items()))
```

Output:

```
1:1: 345435-345-345-34
2:2: 445345-35-34-345-34
3:3: 3445-34534534-34345
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through both the key and the value.

```
for i in numbers:
    print("{}: {}".format(i, numbers[i]))
```

The `.format()` argument I used is a useful tool for formatting string, it simply places variables wherever {} is located in your string. See docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format).